# When an intended exit occurs, rosbag status problem

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all

I am using rosbag to record some data automatically with systemd service in ubuntu.

When an intended exit occurs, the rosbag file is not completed status as *.bag.active.

I tried the bellow commands to restore the file.

`rosbag reindex`

`rosbag fix`

but it was not restored as unknown some problem.

Just It is possible to properly save using `rosnode kill "node_name"`. But it is not automatic system...

I want to know that a rosbag file will be saved properly when it terminates abnormally.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327235/when-an-intended-exit-occurs,-rosbag-status-problem./) by [Han Gyu-dong](https://answers.ros.org/users/43606/han-gyu-dong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds as though you're sending a kill signal to the rosbag node so it's shutting down instantly and not cleaning up the `.bag.active` file. If you can send a `sig int` to shut it down instead then it should correctly close the bag file it's recording.

How is the rosbag node being killed? If you can tell us exactly how this is happening then we can suggest a method that should close out the bag file correctly. If you're doing it from a bash script you could use

```
kill -INT <rosbag PID>
```

to shut it down as if ctrl+c has been pressed.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0